# Parse Issue expected identifier "]"

Tags: objective-c

i know there's a lot of those errors question out there but none of them fixed my error. I tried remove square brackets, adding square brackets, changing retain to return. Nothing worked. Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

destinationDate = [[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:] retain];
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateLabel) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}
```

I get the error under the "]" after dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:]
```

Is missing the argument. How many seconds since 1970 are you specifying? Try something like:

```
[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:100]
```

Comment: Or just `[NSDate date]` if you want the current date/time.

Comment: I entered the timestamp and removed the retain thing and it worked.